# Selection sort with arrays from keyboard in java

Tags: java, selection

Good Morning,
I'm trying to write a code where the user writes some numbers in the keyboard (casually), and the program should write them in order, from the lower to greater.

I don't remember in particular how to insert the number from the keyboard to the array or to the arraylist class if i don't want any limit.

This is my code. i know it is not correct.

```
import java.util.*;
class Ordine {
public static void main (String [] args) {
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in)
System.out.println; ("insert the number which you need to order");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int [] x = new int [200];
            for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        x [i] = s.nextInt();
            for (int j=i+1; j<x.length; j++) {
                if (x[i] > x[j]) {
                //cambia ELEMENTI
                int temp = x[i];
                x[i] = x[j];
                x[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

}
}

Thank you!

Comment: The Scanner API along with System.in will help you to read from standard input. Please explain, what is the exact problem, you are facing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I just wanted to write the int numbers inserted from the user in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

Since array have fixed size you will have to use arraylist. Below is the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,8,9,10,13));
    try{
        while (true)
        {   
            int l=0;int r=a.size()-1,m=0;
            int p=in.nextInt();

            while(l<=r){
                m=(l+r)/2;
                if(a.get(m)>p){
                    l=l;r=m-1;
                }
                if(a.get(m)<p){
                    l=m+1;r=r;
                }
                if(a.get(m)==p){
                    l=m;
                    break;
                }
            }
            a.add(l,p);
            System.out.println("Entered number is: "+p);
            System.out.print("Sorted arraylist is:  ");
            for(int j=0;j<a.size();j++){

                System.out.print(a.get(j)+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

}

I have intitialized the arraylist. And it will print the ordered arraylist everytime you enter a new number.
Below is a sample output[image]